# como hacer que un JButton se active mientras este presionado

Tags: java, java-swing, jbutton

como puedo hacer que un JButton ejecute su acción predeterminada mientras el usuario haga click en él, así como está por defecto toca que el usuario suelte el click y lo vuelva a pulsar si quiere que esto se haga 2 veces.
¿Que técnica debo usar?¿Existe algún método o algún objeto que me permita hacer eso?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prueba a usar un ChangeListener y un Timer:

```
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;

public class Ejemplo {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      int timerDelay = 100;
      final Timer timer = new Timer(timerDelay , new ActionListener() {

         @Override
         public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            System.out.println("Hiciste click!");
         }
      });

      JButton button = new JButton("Clickeame!!");
      final ButtonModel bModel = button.getModel();
      bModel.addChangeListener(new ChangeListener() {

         @Override
         public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent cEvt) {
            if (bModel.isPressed() && !timer.isRunning()) {
               timer.start();
            } else if (!bModel.isPressed() && timer.isRunning()) {
               timer.stop();
            }
         }
      });

      JPanel panel = new JPanel();
      panel.add(button);


      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, panel);

   }
}
```

Como ves el metodo `stateChanged` se encarga de iniziar el timer una vez que el usuario hace click en el botón para luego realizar la acción de escribir en la consola "Hiciste Click".